# "if (int == 1)" doesn't work

Tags: java, if-statement

So I am trying to learn Java, and have been writing a basic program based off of the **21 matches** game; in which each player takes turns taking 1,2 or 3 matches. The player to take the last match loses.

It was going well until I found that when the user was about to win, the program wouldn't enter the final `else if` statement; it would skip over it and come back to the user, without the computer having taken any matches. Attached is the method I have written for the computers turn.

```
public static int ComputerPlays(int matches){ //Method for the computers turn
    int matchesTaken = 0;

    if (matches > 7){ matchesTaken = new Random().nextInt(3)+1; }
    else if (matches > 4 && matches < 8){ matchesTaken = matches - 4; }
    else if (matches < 5){ matchesTaken = matches - 1; }
    else if (matches == 1){ matchesTaken = 1; }

    System.out.println("Computer takes " + matchesTaken + " matches");
    return(matches - matchesTaken);
}
```

The line `else if (matches == 1){ matchesTaken = 1; }` is where I'm having a problem. Any help would be appreciated.

P.S. I realize that I could turn the `else if` into an `else` statement, but the main thing is I want to learn what the problem is, not just get around it.

Comment: if `matches` has the value `1` the part `if (matches < 5){` will be executed thus you'll never reach `if (matches == 1)`

Comment: This code never checks for `matches==1` because `matches < 5` matches first!

Comment: This is where stepping through the code in your debugger would really help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should move the `(matches == 1)` before `(matches < 5)` condition. The code is not reachable till `(matches == 1)` as this condition is satisfied by `(matches < 5)` also.

**Updated code:**

```
public static int ComputerPlays(int matches){ //Method for the computers turn
    int matchesTaken = 0;

    if (matches > 7){ matchesTaken = new Random().nextInt(3)+1; }
    else if (matches > 4 && matches < 8){ matchesTaken = matches - 4; }
    else if (matches == 1){ matchesTaken = 1; }
    else if (matches < 5){ matchesTaken = matches - 1; }

    System.out.println("Computer takes " + matchesTaken + " matches");
    return(matches - matchesTaken);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the matches < 5 will Always be reached Before the  matches == 1 meaning it will never trigger the second if. so either you change order of the if's or add a Another argument to your less than 5 i.e (matches < 5 && matches > 1).

Answer (score 0):

The condition `(matches == 1)` will be unreachable since your previous condtion is always makes your later condition true ie., `if (matches < 5)` which actually considers `matches == 1`. You can make the last two condition as:

```
else if (matches < 5 && matches != 1){ matchesTaken = matches - 1; }
    else if (matches == 1){ matchesTaken = 1; }
```

or like

```
else if (matches < 5 && matches > 1){ matchesTaken = matches - 1; }
    else if (matches == 1){ matchesTaken = 1; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that the statement

```
else if (matches < 5){ matchesTaken = matches - 1; }
```

will be true when the matches is 1. Thus the else if will never be entered. You can change it to

```
else if (matches < 5 && matches != 1){ matchesTaken = matches - 1; }
```

That way, it will not trigger when the number of matches is 1 and the following block can execute successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Put

`else if (matches == 1){ matchesTaken = 1; }`

before

`else if (matches < 5){ matchesTaken = matches - 1; }`

The order is important. In IF_ELSE, once a match is occurs it doesn't check the next condition. In your case as `matches<5` is true it won't check `matches==1`.

Answer (score 0):

You've already checked `else if (matches < 5)` then it's useless checking
`else if (matches == 1)`, because above condition will end the if chain. So you can change 
`else if (matches < 5)` to 
`else if (matches < 5 && matches !=1)` to make the last statement also reachable.

Answer (score 0):

When ever you use else if, use equal conditions (==) first then go for greater than or equal (X>=Y) or less than or equal(X<=Y) conditions.

The statement which satisfies the condition first will execute and rest of else if statements will ignore.

Happy Coding!

Answer (score 0):

```
if (matches > 7){ matchesTaken = new Random().nextInt(3)+1; }
else if (matches > 4 && matches < 8){ matchesTaken = matches - 4; }
else if (matches < 5){ matchesTaken = matches - 1; }
else if (matches == 1){ matchesTaken = 1; }
```

In your code first execute  `else if (matches < 5){ matchesTaken = matches - 1; }`

This line execute first and this line also satisfy if `matches == 1`, thats why it will never goes to the next line (`else if (matches == 1){ matchesTaken = 1; }`) when `matches == 1`

Answer (score 0):

1 is less than 5. This means that when matches is equal to one, it will always be captured in the statement "else if (matches < 5){ matchesTaken = matches - 1; }".

This is the reason why (matches == 1) is never executed.